# How to insert a div in this php code

Tags: php, html

I am listing my posts alphabetically, on top of each section I am displaying the initial letter and the php code is this

```
<?php
        $args=array(
          'post_type' => 'books',
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'posts_per_page'=>-1,
          'caller_get_posts'=>1
        );
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();?>
            <?php
            $this_char = strtoupper(substr($post->post_title,0,1));
            if ($this_char != $last_char) {
              $last_char = $this_char;
              echo '<h3>'.$last_char.'</h3>';

            } ?>
            <p><a data-transition="slide" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"     rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <?php endwhile; } 
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

with and HTML output of

```
<div class="entry-content">
<h3>A</h3>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h3>B</h3>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Now my problem is that I need to insert a div with a data-role of collapsible so it can look like

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div dat-role="collapsible">
    <h3>A</h3>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div dat-role="collapsible">
    <h3>B</h3>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
</div>
```

but I can't. I have tried to echo out the  before the h3 and after the if but it doesn't get me the markup I need. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this code:

```
<?php
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'books',
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'posts_per_page'=>-1,
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();?>
        <?php
        $this_char = strtoupper(substr($post->post_title,0,1));
        if ($this_char != $last_char) {
          $last_char = $this_char;
          if (isset($flag)) 
            echo '</div>';              
          echo '<div class="entry-content">';
          echo '<h3>'.$last_char.'</h3>';
          $flag = true;
        } ?>
        <p><a data-transition="slide" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"     rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php endwhile; } 
        if (isset($flag)) 
            echo '</div>';  
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Yes that's the one! I just changed <div class="entry-content"> for data-role="collapsable" and works perfectly! Thanks a lot! still I am trying to understand how you did it

Comment: It's not so complicated. just add a flag to determine when you open the "div" tag for the first time. then every time you open a div you have to close it. So I checked if it has already opened by checking the flag. Since the last closing tag is skipped, you need to add another checking after endwhile. That's all.

Comment: I know.. I tried, it says I can't vote because I need reputation and I just signed in :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
        $args=array(
          'post_type' => 'books',
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'posts_per_page'=>-1,
          'caller_get_posts'=>1
        );
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();?>
            <?php
            $this_char = strtoupper(substr($post->post_title,0,1));
            if ($this_char != $last_char) {
              $last_char = $this_char;
              echo '<div dat-role="collapsible"><h3>'.$last_char.'</h3>';

            } ?>
            <p><a data-transition="slide" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"     rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <?php endwhile; } 
            echo "</div>";
        wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Yes I tried that too and it prints me back '<div data-role="collapsible">
 <h3>A</h3>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <p></p>
 <div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3>B</h3>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
   <h3>C</h3>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>
   <p></p>'